# unity2d create a one side collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a maplestory game demo

I need character can jump through a collider from one side

the collider in my character and ground are like this:

character:capsulecollider2d

ground:polygoncollider2d

[image]

so the character can stand on the ground

[image][image]

also can jump on the ground

but now I want character jump from bottom of the ground,it cannot work

[image]

so, How can I deal this problem? Is there a configuration that can make collider only have one side?

-------------------------------------2017 08 11-------------------------------------

thanks a lot every one

thank you @EmreE @Jeroen De Clercq

I resolved this problem by using Platform Effector 2D provided by @EmreE

[image]

first: add platform effector 2d on my ground
and select "use one way"

second:select "Used by Effector"

[image]

now it works :)

[image]

Comment: It can be done but requires code. What have you tried?

Comment: This is a great thread that provides a lot of good ideas regarding this issue: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/layers-collision-and-one-way-platforms-a-question.71790/

Comment: Also this could help[Platform Effector 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlatformEffector2D.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Put your floor in a layer;
- put your platforms in a layer;
- When you jump remove collision with platform layer until u have reached a direction that points towards the floor.
- When you press down key remove collision with platforms until you have passed one platform layer.

More information here ; https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision.html

Comment: thank you !I resolved this problem by using Platform Effector 2D

Comment: @Martin If this answer has helped u please accept the answer.Good luck with your game.